# How to add a div with content using asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created a website with a working registration and login.
However, I ran into some trouble when trying to make a little forum.
What I want the forum to do is creating a div containing the message when the user filled a textbox and submitted it by clicking on a button.

The question is, how can I add html to my div by just using code?
This is what I have already.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Message.Text != null)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl post = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            HtmlGenericControl message = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            message.InnerText = Message.Text;
            post.Controls.Add(message);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just a tip, I can help you get it into there with C#... but Jqery/javascript is a much better fit here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a div to container div in c# code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165529/how-to-add-a-div-to-container-div-in-c-sharp-code-behind)

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but I'll have to link the user from the database as well, you can't do that with JS can you?

Comment: Hint: A `Label` Control is a `<div>` in HTML.

Comment: @user6875529, its actually pretty easy to send data to and from js/code behind. Research Jquery AJAX calls. Here is a good example: https://forums.asp.net/t/2086468.aspx?Send+data+from+c+to+jquery+in+same+page

Comment: @Trey I edited my code following the instructions from the thread you linked to, will this work?

Comment: @user6875529, I guess another question would be, why are you creating a new div instead of using an existing one? What message are you trying to display?

Comment: and @Ethilium that certainly looks interesting, will have a look at that as well. And to your new question: it's like posting on a forum.