# How can I generate texbox or label dynamically in specific div class?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am working on a dynamic asp.net page, and ı generate some label and text box in my form page. But ı want to generate them in the specific div class. How can ı solve that problem?

---

Here is codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countStart; i++)    //Create all content of the table in here
{
    //CREATE ALL LABELS
    Label lbl = new Label();
    string colName = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();  //SET LABEL NAME LİKE TABLE COLUMN NAME
    lbl.Text = colName;
    lbl.ID = "lbl" + ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() + i.ToString(); //SET LABEL ID LİKE TABLE COLUMN NAME PLUS İNT İ VALUE

    form1.Controls.Add(lbl);

    Label space = new Label(); space.Text = "                  "; form1.Controls.Add(space);  //SPACE 

    //CREATE ALL TEXT BOES
    TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
    textbox1.ID = "txt" + i.ToString(); //SET TEXT BOX NAME 
    textbox1.Attributes.Add("colVal", colName);  //SET NEW ATTRİBUTES TO TEXTBOX
    textbox1.Width = 500;


    form1.Controls.Add(textbox1);
}
```

Comment: After watching your code: so you want to put a div around your textbox? Is that the question?

Comment: @StevenLemmens ı just want to put my textboxs and label in a div

Comment: What do you mean by _"generate dynamically"_?

Comment: Okay, I haven't tested this, but I believe it's called a `HtmlGenericControl` what you're looking for.  Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816636/11503035. Does this help?

Comment: @vasily.sib ıt is mean, when ı change dropdownlist, textboxes and labels will generate according to tables column number.

Comment: @HüseyinÖzkoç - does you web page reloads everytime you change dropdownlist?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes it does.

Comment: @HüseyinÖzkoç ok, then how do you generate that `div` that you want to use?

Comment: @vasily.sib ı just want to put my generated boxes and labels in a div which releated with html side.

Answer (score 0):

use Panel as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countStart; i++)    //Create all content of the table in here
{
    //CREATE ALL LABELS
    var p = new Panel();
    p.ID = "pnl" + ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() + i.ToString();
    form1.Controls.Add(p);

    ...

    p.Controls.Add(lbl);

    ...

    p.Controls.Add(space);  //SPACE 

    ...


    p.Controls.Add(textbox1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose if a label exists in div, then find the label by its container like div.

```
<div id="divLbl" runat="server">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblToolsTechnology1" />
  </div>

 Label label = (Label)divLbl.FindControl("lblToolsTechnology1");
```